# RegularExpressionValidator slow on multiline textbox (textarea)

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I have a multiline textbox (textarea) that I want to verify has a particular string in it. I was trying:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtTemplate" ValidationExpression="^(.\s*)*Content(.\s*)*$" Text="content" ErrorMessage="Must contain: Content" />
```

Using `^(.\s*)*$` seems to pass for a textarea. So I tried to sandwich my criteria between two of these. But it seems to lock up both IE and Chrome.

This should be simple, I think I'm making it tougher than it needs to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the validation is always being done on the server (that's what `runat="server"` means, isn't it?), the simplest solution is probably to use this regex:

```
(?s)^.*Content.*$
```

`(?s)` turns on `Singleline` mode, which allows the `.` metacharacter to match all characters *including* linefeeds.  If you want it to run on the client as well, use this:

```
^[\s\S]*Content[\s\S]*$
```

That's because JavaScript has no equivalent for `Singleline` mode (also known as `DOT_ALL`, `DOTALL`, *dot-matches-all*, *single-line*, or `/s` mode).  It doesn't recognize inline modifiers like `(?s)` and `(?i)`, either.

Watch out for constructs like `(.\s*)*`, where an expression with quantifiers (`*`, `+`, etc.) is enclosed in a group which is itself controlled by a quantifier.  If the regex fails to achieve a match right away, it goes back and tries to match by different paths (i.e., by using different parts of the regex to match different parts of the string), which can get very expensive, performance-wise.  This regex is especially bad because `.` and `\s` can match many of the same characters, which dramatically increases the number of paths it has to explore before giving up.

The phenomenon is commonly known as [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html), and it usually manifests in cases where there's no possibility of a match.  I would expect your validator to work fine when the sequence `Content` is present.

By the way, if you want to match only on the complete word `Content`, you should add word boundaries, like so:

```
(?s)^.*\bContent\b.*$
```

That will prevent false positives on words like `MalContent` and `Contentious`.  `\b` works differently in different regex flavors.  In .NET it's Unicode-aware unless you specify `ECMAScript` mode.  In JavaScript it's supposed to recognize only the *ASCII* letters and digits as word characters; in most browsers it does, but don't take it for granted.

Comment: Awesome answer. I used the [\s\S] option since I wanted it to run on the client-side also (runat="server" means the server has to interpret the tag, EnableClientScript="false" would only run it on the server).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
[\S\s]*Content[\S\s]*
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a regex more like `.*Content.*` would be more effective and possibly faster. Also, you may want to implement a custom validator if this continues to be a performance drag, where you use JavaScript to search the text for the string.

Comment: Doesn't work. The period doesn't catch newlines, that's why I was including the "\s" (whitespace). I could do a custom validator, but that's like eight more lines of code :)